# the output of color.label2rgb in skimage

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-learn, computer-vision, scikit-image

In the [normalized cut code segment](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_ncut.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-segmentation-plot-ncut-py), I am not very clear about the output of **color.label2rgb**.

```
labels1 = segmentation.slic(img, compactness=30, n_segments=400)
out1 = color.label2rgb(labels1, img, kind='avg')
```

when I output the result of **labels1** and the different dimensions of **out1**, looks like the result of **out1** does not match the entry values in **labels1**. What are the meanings of the entry values in **out1**. How do they relate to the label IDs in **labels1**?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`segmentation.slic` will segment the image using k-means clustering in Color-(x,y,z) space.

`np.unique(labels1)` will give you the labels.

---

Next, `color.label2rgb` returns an RGB image where color-coded labels are painted over the image.

`out1.shape` returns (400, 600, 3) and this is the result of blending a cycling colormap (colors) for each distinct value in label with the image, at a certain alpha value.

Also, there is a default input argument in `color.label2rgb` named `kind`.

> The kind of color image desired. ‘overlay’ cycles over defined colors
>   and overlays the colored labels over the original image. ‘avg’
>   replaces each labeled segment with its average color, for a
>   stained-class or pastel painting appearance.

So in your case, you replace each labeled segment with its average color, for a stained-class or pastel painting appearance.